# Formatting Double with two dp

Tags: java, android

From my decimalForm method below, i want to convert double value 7777.54 to 7 777,54 but i am getting 7 777 54. what have missed ? result should be 7 777,54

```
public static String decimalForm(double value){

            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.00");
            String formatted_value = df.format(value).replaceAll(",", " ").replace(".", ",");

            return formatted_value;
        }
```

Comment: Have u tried replacing the .00 for .## ?

Comment: yes but getting 7 777 54

Comment: @PankajKumar Break each statement how? Not a useful comment as it stands.

Comment: @EJP Ok. I am removing... I was trying to say that OP should write 3 different statements instead of single. And also I said this CAN (not the solution) do the job...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.00");
String formatted_value = df.format(value).replaceAll("\\.", " ");
```

In fact i tried to print out `df.format(value)` and, with `value=95871` i got `95.871,00`

Comment: @PankajKumar It does. `replaceAll` accepts a regex and if you just use `.` you will have an empty string, because everything gets replaced.

Comment: @Pankaj &&  BackSlash, nice thank you it works. yes, i learned something new today :)

Comment: wait 6 minutes because of stackoverflow restriction

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
 String formatted_value = String.format("$%.2f", value);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the pattern `#,###,###.00`, `.` is the decimal separator and `,` is the group separator. The character used for this two separators depends on your locale.

For example, if you are french, `df.format(value)` will equals to `7 777,54`.

Answer (score 0):

This is no String.replace version

```
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#,###,###.00", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.FRANCE));
    String s = df.format(7777.54);
    System.out.println(s);
```

output

```
7 777,54
```